# How to update UICollectionView with another array when click on cell?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have 3 collection views on one viewcontroller, how to update another collection view data when i click on one collectionview cell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        if collectionView == CollectionViewBottom
        {
            if indexPath.item == 14
            {
           ////what code i should write here to update collection view
                HeadingLabel.text = "Solar"
               CollectionViewMID.reloadData()

            }
         }         
}
```

Comment: seems like you solved it. keep all 3 collection views as vars in your vc, then call .reloadData() on the desired collection any time.

Comment: But i want to update with another data from array ?

Comment: cell.ImageMid.image = self.imagesArrayMidGenerator[indexPath.row] in this way adding data to collectionview in itematindex path , but now i want to update this collection view with  cell.ImageMid.image = self.solarArray[indexPath.row]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an example for you. Hope it will help you

```
var arr : [String] = []

var collectionView:UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    arr = ["ONE","TWO","THREE"]
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
   if indexPath.row == 1
   {
       arr = ["ABC", "EFG", "HIJ"]
       collectionView.reloadData()
   }
   else if indexPath.row == 2
   {
       arr = ["1", "2", "3"]
       collectionView.reloadData()
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brother for help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question Than You can simply solve it by raload others collectionView Data inside `didSelectRowAtindexPath`For example :

three collectionView Instance is :

```
var collectionViewOne:UICollectionView!
var collectionViewTwo:UICollectionView!
var collectionViewThree:UICollectionView!
```

So In the CollectionViewViewThree `didSelectRowAtindexPath`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
  //apply your logic in this Scope 
    if ( your logic ) {
       collectionViewOne.realoadData()
       collectionViewTwo.realoadData()
       } 

    }
```

Comment: cell.ImageMid.image = self.imagesArrayMidGenerator[indexPath.row] in this way adding data to collectionview in itematindex path , but now i want to update this collection view with new array data cell.ImageMid.image = self.solarArray[indexPath.row]

Comment: What do you mean by `ImageMid` .Cant understand your question properly can you show code ?

Comment: imageMid is the outlet of imageview in cell class where image is going to be update

Comment: oky So you just want to update cell newImage with  imageArray `self.solarArray[indexPath.row]1` to when user click cell ?

Comment: when user click on a cell in BottomCollectionView then the data in Mid Collectionview updated how i can do this ?

Comment: Mid collection view already have data but when i click on a bottom Collection view cell new data from array should be updated on a midCollectionview

Answer (score 0):

Oky Create a property Observer Like this top pf the `viewDidLoad` like this

```
var updateDataArray:[String]  = [String](){
        didSet {
            print(oldValue)
            reloadData()
        }
    }
```

than in your button collectionView DidselectRowAtindexpath

````
updateDataArray = your newDataArray``

and in the reload data 

```func reloadData() {
   yourtableView.reloadData()
}
````

Comment: but this code only saving data to another array not showing in collection view?